# How to get return value of IIFE?

Tags: javascript, iife

I have the following IIFE in a file `iife.js`:

```
(function() {
    return "Hello World!";
}());
```

I would like to get the result of this function in another file:

```
var result = require("./iife");
console.log(result);
```

But the `result` is `{}` instead of `Hello World!`.

How can I access the return value of the IIFE from another file, preferably without changing the code in `iife.js`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to capture it on the left hand side:

```
const return_value = (function() {
    return "Hello World!";
}());
```

But if you want to export it from a CommonJS module then you need to assign it to the module's exports:

```
module.exports = return_value;
```

But if you are using a CommonJS module then there is no point in using an IIFE in the first place. IIFEs are used to isolate variables, which modules do anyway.

```
module.exports = "Hello World!";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can I achieve the same thing without changing the code in `iife.js`?